# Is there any way to inverse tensorflow predicted variable to origin value?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, tensorflow2.0

I have run tensorflow 2.0 algorithm where my dependent variable is y in label format

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

while predicting model got scaling value from tensorflow.

```
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
# fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_pred[0:10]

array([[1.8975088e-02, 9.2321676e-01, 5.7808172e-02],
       [2.1689970e-03, 1.1041342e-02, 9.8678964e-01],
       [9.7219455e-01, 2.1523101e-02, 6.2822714e-03],
       [8.9549669e-04, 9.9892455e-01, 1.7989198e-04],
       [5.9214713e-06, 9.9999106e-01, 2.9540893e-06],
       [1.5215098e-05, 9.9994588e-01, 3.8917195e-05],
       [3.2570759e-05, 9.9996614e-01, 1.3605905e-06],
       [2.5089746e-03, 9.9069571e-01, 6.7953388e-03],
       [2.3909420e-02, 9.6926796e-01, 6.8226634e-03],
       [2.9210409e-04, 9.9955446e-01, 1.5343193e-04]], dtype=float32)
```

It must be come as numerical category between 0,1 and 2 but showing some other value.how we can achieve original value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.argmax()` to get indices:

```
ind = tf.argmax(y_pred, -1)
```